# Sending file to server iOS with two parameters iOS

Tags: ios, file-upload

I want to send file to server path with a paramater "filepath" as one parameter, and file data as another paramater. How do I do it.Here in the following I am appending filepath with data. but I guess it is wrong please help

```
NSURL *nsurl =[NSURL URLWithString:_urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request setURL:nsurl];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"Model.png"],  0.0);
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"filepath=%@",_filePath];

NSData *pathData = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[body appendData:pathData];

//Image
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",@"newFile.png"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",dict);
```

thanks

Comment: Show the code you have tried and explain what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just do `[body appendData:pathData];` at the start. You need to add it with the appropriate boundary and content information. So you should have a number of lines like:

1. Add the boundary
2. Add the content info
3. Add the content data
4. Add the boundary

And repeat from 2 for each additional piece of data to be added.

Check the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4) for information on the appropriate content types and disposition info that needs to be added for each data type (perfect example for you is at the bottom).

Comment: you mean to say I have to the same which I did for file data to file path also?

Comment: similar, if it isn't a file then you don't have the same content info (but you need to specify the content info).